# Alphanumeric Icons - cannot find a collection and cannot draw them properly

Tags: icon

I don't know what else to call them.  I googled for simple icon collections
that combine a letter and number like G5, S3, or Z2.  Maybe my search
results produced nothing because they are listed under a different name,
not alphanumeric.

I've tried many times to create my own icons. I have two icon creation apps.  Almost any image looks ok when it's big. Icons are usually very small, like toolbar and menu icons. Typically, 16x16 pixels. When I shrink and save my images as an icon they look horrible. Maybe I'm using the wrong apps. If it exists, can you recommend an app that will produce clear icons after the image is reduced to toolbar or menu size?

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - *Please* look through **[tour]** to get a sense of our community – who we are and what we’re about. *Then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes a good query here, *and* how best to frame it. We ***do*** ask that your question shows your *effort*: tell us what you already know and understood; show us what you tried and failed;illustrate your question with sketches, screenshots or examples; please read [ask] and [edit]  your question to better fit our guidelines. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

About drawing them:

16 x 16 pixels isn't much for two readable characters. By using normal computer fonts in such small size you get (at best) something like this:

[image]

It's a high zoom screenshot of text 9A, the width was 16 pixels on the screen. It has got some very clever math processing. The screenshot was taken from Opera web browser. It was well readable on my 1200 px and 325 mm high screen at distance 70 cm.

If you try to get the same, you should write the text in the final size and let the font rendering software do the clever job. You can take a screenshot like me.

If you write it in a big size and scale down the rendered image, you will get unreadable mess. Scaling text keeping the readability is a complex thing which has needed very much research. Every part of the results fortunately isn't behind software patents, so we have also pretty well working free graphic software and operating systems GUIs.

There's another way. You can use some **bitmap font** which is developed for low resolution. Here's a portion of the character table of one such font.

[image]

Plenty of bitmap fonts are available for free.

I guess the decorations must be quite minimal. If you need some, you must work like a pixel artist and build the image in the final resolution. Scaling down works only in some lucky cases.